# How to retain the pickerInput liveSearch filter. Now the filters get reset once a selection is made

Tags: r, shiny

Once you search something in the liveSearch and select some option from the pickerInput drop-down the liveSearch filters are gone and the whole choices of the pickerInput is displayed.

> **Example:** Assume that I have a list of many fruits and vegetables as
>   choices in the drop-down and I need to select only some fruits, So I
>   type in "Fruit" in the liveSearch and I get Apple, Banana and Orange.
>   I need to select Apple and Orange so I go ahead and select Apple
>   first, but in doing so the liveSearch gets reset and I'm left with the
>   whole list.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(12, br()),
        column(
            3,
            pickerInput(
                inputId = 'product_in', label = 'Select the products',
                multiple = TRUE,
                choices = c(
                    'Fruit_Apple', 'Fruit_Banana', 'Fruit_Orange',
                    'Vegetable_Broccoli', 'Vegetable_Cabbage', 'Vegetable_Lettuce'
                ),
                options = pickerOptions(
                    liveSearch = TRUE,
                    liveSearchPlaceholder = 'Search questions',
                    dropdownAlignRight = TRUE,
                    size = 5,
                    selectedTextFormat = 'count > 1',
                    countSelectedText = '{0} questions selected'
                )
            )
        ),
        column(9, verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "selectionOutput"))
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$selectionOutput <- renderPrint({
        input$product_in
    })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Updating the shinyWidgets fixed this!